# How to check if a multipart file is a zip file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipart, zip

I would like to do a simple check if a MultipartFile from  org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile7 is in fact a ZIP file. Is there an elegant way to do this without doing a lot of conversion?

One solution is to convert MultipartFile to java.io.File and than use it to create a ZipFile object, whose constructor throws an ZipException, if the file is not an actual ZIP.
In my opinion this is not a nice solution as it takes a fair number of code lines, but I could not come up with anything better.
Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use  File Name utils from Apache Commons IO

```
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename())
        if(extension.equals(".zip"){
        // enter logic here  
        }
```

Maven Dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```